# auto specifier with function pointer - C++

Tags: c++, c++14

Below code has argument(with `auto` specifier) of function pointer,

```
void g( bool(*fptr)(const auto) ){
  //
}

bool f(const int a){
  //
}
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  g(&f); // Error
}
```

works fine.

---

With this code,

```
bool k(const auto); // Compiler accepts declaration with auto specifier
auto h(auto& output, const auto& value) // Compiler accepts definition with auto specifier
{
   // output << value << "\n";
}
typedef bool(*fptr)(const auto); // Error 
void g( fptr f ){
  //
}

bool f(const int a){
  //
}
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  g(&f);
}
```

`g++ -std=c++14` says, `error: non-function ‘fptr’ declared as implicit template`

---

**Question:**

Why C++ compiler does not allow `auto` with function pointers?

Comment: `auto` means that the compiler is to automatically deduce the type. How would you expect it to deduce the type of a function's parameter from a function pointer declaration? The only reason that `auto` even works in the declaration of e.g. the `k` function is because GCC supports an early version of the "Concepts" proposal as an extension. This is *not* ISO C++.

Comment: auto parameters is not a part of standard C++, though it might be partially supported by gcc.

Comment: @CodyGray How would you expect it to deduce the type of a function's parameter from a function declaration(`bool k(const auto);`) or definition?

Comment: auto parameters are part of the Concepts TS which is not part of the standard (yet). Any solution to the presented problem would be pointless.

Comment: Well, it can't, not from that alone. It needs [more information](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concepts_(C%2B%2B)).

Comment: Side note: I think you're misusing typedef. You need a name to call your typedef by, not just what the type is.

Answer (score 6):

`auto` in function parameters is a gcc extension, although it will be standardized when Concepts TS gets merged.

I never used this extension, but this is probably just a shortcut for a template declaration, i.e.

```
void g( bool(*fptr)(const auto) ) {}

template<typename T>
void g( bool(*fptr)(const T) ) {}
```

are both equivalent. You cannot use templates in a `typedef` declaration, you have to use a `using` declaration:

```
using fptr = bool(*)(const auto); // ok
```

For some reason the code will still not compile because it cannot convert `decltype(&f)` (which is a `bool(*)(int)`) to `fptr`. That's the extension's fault. Using Standard C++ your code compiles fine:

```
template<typename T>
using fptr = bool(*)(const T);

template<typename T>
void g( fptr<T> fa ) {}
```

Comment: IIUC `using fptr = bool(*)(const auto);` is not OK (the alias declaration will not be automatically turned into a template declaration) even in Concepts TS.

Comment: @cpplearner I have no idea about Concepts TS, but the error when using it in `typedef` hints that it is in fact a template, although it is not usable as such because it is implicit/compiler generated.

Comment: [I guess this is a bug, not a feature.](https://wandbox.org/permlink/HDLWOb0zVCOam5jO)